# Difference between assigning React ref using a callback versus setting it directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

It works and behaves the same, but wanted to know if there are any practical differences to setting a ref directly versus setting it via a callback that has the element as an argument.

Given this react hook component:

```
const myComponent = ({ ...props}) => {
  const myRef = React.useRef(null);

  ...

  return (
    <div>
      ref={myRef}
    </div>
  )
}
```

versus

```
const myComponent = ({ ...props}) => {
  const myRef = React.useRef(null);

  ...

  return (
    <div>
      ref={element => {
        myRef.current = element;        
      }}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are similar as per the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) docs:

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue).

So, first example of code will work exactly like the second example of code.

Except

> If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.

Meaning; if you want to re-render the component then you can use the callback ref.

---

Best example from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) itself:

**To measure the position or size of a DOM node**

```
function MeasureExample() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
      <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

So, you can find the height of the element will be changed by using callback ref. If you were not using callback ref, then it wouldn't have been re-rendered and no content height would have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with first approach you can't notify when its content changes, mutating the `.current` property will not re-render it, but using a `callback ref` you can run some code, based on your use-case, when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node.

For the callback approach, you really don't need to use `useRef` instead you can use `useCallback`. here is an example from React documentation :

```
function MeasureExample() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
  if (node !== null) {
     setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
  }
  }, []);

    return (
   <>
     <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
     <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
   </>
 );
}
```