# In React: What can be achieved by putting an arrow function into a ref statement within the JSX code (using useRef)?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

Recently, I have found the following code while trying to find an efficient way to retrieve the values of several "entries" on a form through useRef:

```js
const inputRef = useRef({});
...
<input ref={el => inputRef.current['firstName'] = el} ... />
<input ref={el => inputRef.current['lastName'] = el} ... />
```

Before, I have only seen examples such as:

```js
const firstName = useRef(null);
const lastName = userRef(null);
...
<input ref={firstName} ... />
<input ref={lastName} ... />
```

What can be achieved by putting an arrow function instead of a const into the JSX code? What are the "mechanisms" that are being used here? I have never manipulated the `.current` attribute directly. Is that approach kind of a "best practice"? Or should it be avoided?

Comment: You can pretty much do whatever you want with `.current`. Here, the main difference is how the `ref` is initialized. React supports both patterns, either passing a ref directly where React populates the `current` property automatically or passing a function and you get to do whatever you want with the received `el` element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between assigning React ref using a callback versus setting it directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204134/difference-between-assigning-react-ref-using-a-callback-versus-setting-it-direct)